# How to avoid writing thousands of variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, if-statement

(I'm a beginner). If I wanted to set up a system for asking questions and returning user-inputted answers using if statements and variables, there will be a large amount of potential combinations of answers and I feel like I would be forced to write out a variable for every name in the world for example, and then do that again but with every potential age/name combination, etc. Obviously there is an easier solution. How do most people tackle this?

I've tried this:

```
var yourName = prompt("What's your name?");


if (yourName == prompt.value) {
    console.log("It worked!");
}
```

It doesn't work, nothing shows up in console.

important: Can this be done with only if statements, variables, functions and arrays? Or will I have to use objects and switch statements?

edit: (this is just an example about shopping):

```
function selectPants () {

    var jeans = "jeans";
    var khakis = "khakis";

    var yourPants = prompt("What kind of pants do you want?");



    if (yourPants == jeans) {
        console.log("Okay, that will cost $10."), selectShirt ();
    } 
}   

function selectShirt () {

    var plaid = "plaid";
    var v-neck = "v-neck";


    var yourShirt = prompt("What shirt do you want?");

    if (yourShirt == plaid) {
      console.log("Okay, that will cost $5, your total so far is: ??"), selectShoes ();
    }
}


    selectPants ();
```

As you can see I would also need some addition system to add up the costs. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Because prompt is a function, not an object, and has no properties to be accessed. The user-entered value is now stored in the `yourName` variable; so what is it you're trying to test here?

Comment: Could you provide more of an example of these "combinations". I suspect you are going to be using if-else statements.

Comment: Okay I updated it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to have a question object (for each question) that will be stored in a questions collection.
The collection would be an array in javascript.

You can then iterate over each question, prompt them and save the answer back to each question object.

```
// collection of questions. answers are empty to start with
var questions = [{ "question" : "Whats your name", "answer": ""},
                 { "question" : "What is your age", "answer": ""}];

// Ask all the questions
for(var i=0,len = questions.length; i < len; i++){
  var ans = prompt(questions[i].question);
  questions[i].answer = ans; // store your answer
}  

// see what is the answer for the first question.
console.log(questions[0].answer);
```

Comment: Okay nice, I needed to know that, but I also want to know whether it's possible to do with variables. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: i dont see any specific benefit over using variables. when you start storing everything in variables. it will be just get clumsy. this way ,you could store all your questions as a JSON string and load them whenever you need. this also gives you the opportunity to edit questions outside of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt is a function not a class, prompt."something" means nothing, you must write prompt()

```js
var yourName = prompt("What's your name?");


if (yourName == prompt()) {
    console.log("It worked!"); // Open your console to see this
}
```

Comment: And...what do you think the OP is trying to do with this code?

Comment: **quote from the question** _set up a system for asking questions and returning user-inputted answers_

Comment: Indeed, but the code you've written (and his, from the question) bears no resemblance to that described intent.

Comment: I just gave a little help about the prompt function, Mike did better: giving a code that actually does it.